# Mongodb updates latest record instead of creating a new one

Tags: spring, mongodb, indexing, mongotemplate

I have a task that runs on production server and creates a record once a day every day. The thing is, it's not doing so anymore, instead, it updates latest record. But with local database everything works perfectly fine. A new record is created every day and the previous one is kept.

I looked at indexes but they are identical in production and local database. I made a dump of production database and ran daily task locally, and the new values are not created so I'm sure that there is an issue with the production database.
I use MongoTemplate to insert data: `Saving DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, version, date, close, etc..]` so it's basically `db.daily_task.insert()`

```
    {
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
    "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "test.daily_task"
    },
    {
    "v" : 2,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
    "date" : 1,
    "fname" : 1
    },
    "name" : "date_1_fname_1",
    "ns" : "test.daily_task"
    },
    {
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
    "fname" : 1
    },
    "name" : "fname_1",
    "ns" : "test.daily_task"
    }
```

Setting `unique` to `false` didn't do anything too. I'm not sure what might cause this issue. Help pls.

Comment: Hi Kyrylo, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a chance to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As a rule of thumb - try to read the question like you have never heard about the problem and cannot easily access the production database. You will probably notice that few bits are missing. I can assure you it's totally fine for the same query to act differently on different datasets with or without indexes. Please add at least the query.

Comment: @AlexBlex I updated the question. Let me know if I can provide any additional data

Comment: Thank you sir, hopefully it makes sense to someone with decent experience in MongoTemplate. The best think I can do from my side is to add corresponding tags.